# Bootstrap-Image-Gallery doesn't show full images

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, blueimp, bootstrap-image-gallery

I can't make the simplest [Bootstrap-Image-Gallery](https://github.com/blueimp/Bootstrap-Image-Gallery) example work.

I have the following HTML from their site:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/blueimp-gallery/css/blueimp-gallery.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/Bootstrap-Image-Gallery/css/bootstrap-image-gallery.min.css">
</head>
<body>
  <!-- The Bootstrap Image Gallery lightbox, should be a child element of the document body -->
  <div id="blueimp-gallery" class="blueimp-gallery">
      <!-- The container for the modal slides -->
      <div class="slides"></div>
      <!-- Controls for the borderless lightbox -->
      <h3 class="title"></h3>
      <a class="prev">‹</a>
      <a class="next">›</a>
      <a class="close">×</a>
      <a class="play-pause"></a>
      <ol class="indicator"></ol>
      <!-- The modal dialog, which will be used to wrap the lightbox content -->
      <div class="modal fade">
          <div class="modal-dialog">
              <div class="modal-content">
                  <div class="modal-header">
                      <button type="button" class="close" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                      <h4 class="modal-title"></h4>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-body next"></div>
                  <div class="modal-footer">
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default pull-left prev">
                          <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></i>
                          Previous
                      </button>
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary next">
                          Next
                          <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i>
                      </button>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div id="links">
      <a href="images/banana.jpg" title="Banana" data-gallery>
          <img src="images/thumb.jpg" alt="Banana">
      </a>
  </div>
  <script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/blueimp-gallery/js/jquery.blueimp-gallery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/Bootstrap-Image-Gallery/js/bootstrap-image-gallery.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

It shows banana's thumbnail image but when I click it, page just becomes black and nothing happens.

Why? What am I doing wrong?

All prerequesities were satisfied:

- [jQuery](https://jquery.com/) 3.1.0
- [Gallery](https://github.com/blueimp/Gallery) 2.21.3
- [Bootstrap-Image-Gallery](https://github.com/blueimp/Bootstrap-Image-Gallery) 3.4.2

No errors in console.

Comment: Have you tried putting the scripts in the head instead?

Comment: Also, in the github, it says that blueimpv2.16.0 is required. Was it added?

Comment: @Kode.Error404 Yes, I'm using Gallery 2.21.3

Answer (score 0):

Ah, it seems that Bootstrap-Image-Gallery (or Gallery itself) cannot work with jQuery 3.1.0.

jQuery 1.11.3 works as expected.